# Update Dynamics form field when item is selected on another field

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Dynamics entity that has a relationship to another entity with a Main form in UX. I have a lookup control on the form to select that related entity. Doing so correctly writes the ID of that related entity record to the current record being edited. I need help grabbing the name value of that linked entity and writing it to the name value of the current record when the lookup selection changes. The form designer makes this so much more difficult than it needs to be! Is there a set of basic jscript libraries that I can add to my solution and call for such simple tasks?

Comment: Is there a code to share ? Or screenshot ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth-MVP are you familiar with Dynamics Form Designer (new or the classic version)? I prefer the classic version. When you double click a form field to view it's properties, on the Events tab you can select an Event Handler from an existing library. The handlers are basically javascript functions, where as the libraries is a full script block statement containing the functions (a js file).

Assuming I need something like this:

function updateNameField() {
     var name = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('linkedentityidname');
     Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name').setValue(name);
     }

Comment: Pls edit the question and update it

Comment: @ArunVinoth-MVP the question was looking for any solution. I commented on 1 potential route. There are others, like using Business Rules, workflows, etc. The least amount of overhead seems to be javascript from the onchange event of the form property. I did finally get that to work, and posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After literally HOURS of hunting down bits and pieces, I finally got this to work!

```
function updateName(){
 var name = "";
 var lookupField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lookupentityproperty");

 // Verify the field does exist on the form and has a selected value
 if (lookupField != null && lookupField.getValue() != null && lookupField.getValue()[0] != null) {
      name = lookupField.getValue()[0].name;
 }
 else { name = null; }

 var nameField= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("nameproperty");
 nameField.setValue(name);
}
```